# how to add multiple sector and call functions from that sector in assembly

Tags: assembly, x86-16

FOllowing the the program I have writed with the help of internet
of Boot sector :
anyone Please help me

**1.** is all the sectors are loading fine, how I can load all sectors correctly.

**2.** How I jump from second to third and return

**BOOTSECTOR:**

```
   [bits 16]
[org 0x7c00]

cli
mov bx,cs
mov ds,bx
mov ss,bx
mov sp,0xfffe

mov ax,0 
mov es,ax
mov ax,0x6000
mov word [es:0],0
mov [es:2],ax

mov bx,0x6000
mov es,bx
mov bx,0
sti

mov ah,2 ;service
mov al,1 ;sector count
mov ch,0 ;cylinder
mov cl,2 ;sbector#
mov dh,0 ;head
mov dl,0
int 13h

jc error

;int 0h
mov bx,0
mov es,bx
mov bx,0h
jmp far[es:bx] 

error:
mov al,'E'
mov ah,0eh
mov bl,7
mov bh,0
int 10h
jmp $

k:
mov al,'F'
mov ah,0eh
mov bl,7
mov bh,0
int 10h
jmp $

times 510-($-$$) db 0
dw 0xAA55
```

**Sector2 :**

```
    [bits 16]

SECTOR2:

mov bx,cs
mov ds,bx 
mov es,bx

mov ah,0eh
mov bl,7
mov bh,0 
int 10h

call SECTOR3
mov si,msg2
l:
cmp byte [si],0
je exit
mov al,[si]
int 10h
inc si
jmp l
exit:
jmp $
msg2 db "Sector 2 is loaded",0
times 512-($-$$) db 0
```

**SECtor3:**

```
     [bits 16]

SECTOR3:

mov bx,cs
mov ds,bx 
mov es,bx



     mov ah,0eh
mov bl,7
mov bh,0 
int 10h
 mov si,msg1
l2:
cmp byte [si],0
je exit3
mov al,[si]
int 10h
inc si
jmp l2
exit3:
retf 
; jmp $
msg1 db "Sector 3 is loaded",0
times 512-($-$$) db 0
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all : with vast amounts of memory available you should not abuse the Divide-by-Zero Exception the way you've done!
But on a brighter sight you do load the 2nd sector at 6000h:0000h and `jmp far` to it. The method used can be repeated within the 2nd sector to load the 3rd sector at 6000h:0200h but this time use `call far` to jump to it. Your 3rd sector has a `retf` in the right place.
So loose `call SECTOR3` and at the label 'exit:' make all necessary modifications replacing `jmp $`.